# Nested lists and foreach loops

Tags: c#, list

I want to add a single row to the table from the two lists. i am getting an error in the second foreach loop. **Cannot convert Liability.LiabilityCheckpointInstance to Liability.LiabilityAssignment.**

```
foreach (LiabilityCheckpointInstance ci in value)
{
    //foreach (LiabilityAssignment la in value)
    //{
    var tr = new TableRow();
    var tc = new TableCell { Text = ci.CheckGroup };
    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
    tc = new TableCell { Text  = ci.IxCheck.ToString() };
    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
    tc = new TableCell { Text = ci.CheckPointInfo.ToString() };
    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
    tc = new TableCell { Text = ci.RejectedBy };
    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
    tc = new TableCell { Text = ci.Role };
    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
    tc = new TableCell { Text = ci.Mistakes.ToString() };
    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
    //ChkpLiabilityDataTable.Rows.Add(tr);
    foreach (LiabilityAssignment la in value )
    {
        //var tr = new TableRow();
         tc = new TableCell { Text = la.LiabileOrganizationName };
        tc = new TableCell { Text = la.LiabileOrganizationName };
        tr.Cells.Add(tc);
        tc = new TableCell { Text = la.LiablePersonName };
        tr.Cells.Add(tc);
        tc = new TableCell { Text = la.Comment };
        tr.Cells.Add(tc);
        ChkpLiabilityDataTable.Rows.Add(tr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `LiabilityCheckpointInstance` have a list of `LiabilityAssignment`?

Comment: Didn't you mean something like `foreach (LiabilityAssignment la in ci.XXXX)` for your second `foreach` loop?

Comment: The use of var makes me ill X(

Comment: @CSharpened: why out of interest?

Comment: value is an instance of LiabilityCheckpointInstance type; it is not an instance of LiabilityAssignment type. No conversion is defined, and it seems no inheritance between two classes. The behaviour seems proper.

Comment: The use of `var` makes me feel wonderful.

Comment: For what its worth I use `var` when its either an anonymous type (eg linq things) or if the type is obvious from the delcaration. eg rather than repeating with `Type foo = new Type();` I'll just use `var foo = new Type();`. With something short like that it hardly makes a difference but with a long objet name I think it looks much more readable with a var.

Comment: @Chris Just being picky I guess because in this instance it is not at all necessary. The OP is not using anonymous types etc. It is generally a bad habit that some get into. It is likely to cause a few problems through overuse and should only really be encouraged for the purpose it was intended for. Over use of var also makes reading your code a pain in the backside for people who are forced to. It just isn't something I like to see being used flippantly as it often indicates overuse and bad practice in terms of other people working with your code in the long run. Just my two pence of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick for you.

```
foreach (LiabilityCheckpointInstance ci in value)
{
    var tr = new TableRow();
    var tc = new TableCell { Text = ci.CheckGroup };
    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
    tc = new TableCell { Text  = ci.IxCheck.ToString() };
    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
    tc = new TableCell { Text = ci.CheckPointInfo.ToString() };
    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
    tc = new TableCell { Text = ci.RejectedBy };
    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
    tc = new TableCell { Text = ci.Role };
    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
    tc = new TableCell { Text = ci.Mistakes.ToString() };
    tr.Cells.Add(tc);

    // YOU NEED TO BUILD THESE UP FRONT SO YOU CAN LOOP THROUGH THE
    // CHILDREN SAFELY BELOW
    tr.Cells.Add(new TableCell());
    tr.Cells.Add(new TableCell());
    tr.Cells.Add(new TableCell());

    // I DON'T KNOW IF YOUR PROPERTY IS NAMED LiabilityAssignments OR NOT
    // SO REPLACE THAT WITH WHAT EVER IS NECESSARY - BUT IT SHOULD BE THE
    // LIST OF LiabilityAssignment ON THE LiabilityCheckpointInstance OBJECT
    foreach (LiabilityAssignment la in ci.LiabilityAssignments)
    {
        tr.Cells[6].Text = la.LiabileOrganizationName;
        tr.Cells[7].Text = la.LiablePersonName;
        tr.Cells[8].Text = la.Comment;

        ChkpLiabilityDataTable.Rows.Add(tr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your foreach loops are:

```
foreach (LiabilityCheckpointInstance ci in value)
foreach (LiabilityAssignment la in value )
```

It is looping over the same thing (`value`) but saying the items in it are different. [1]

I would assume from the context that the second should be looping over `ci.something` rather than just value.

So you would have:

```
foreach (LiabilityAssignment la in ci.Something )
```

Of course you will need to change the `Something` to whatever your list is.

[1] I should note that the syntax itself is not incorrect. If the items in value is of both types then (eg one is a subtype of the other) it would work fine. This doesn't look like it is the case here though.

Comment: I want to merge the data from the two lists into a single row in the table. In the LiabilityCheckpointInstance class I have declared a list of Liability Assignment class.

Comment: @ManojNayak: So that list of `LiabilityAssignment` will be `ci.Assignments` or something like that. I've added in some clarification on that point.

Answer (score 1):

Second loop should be

```
foreach (LiabilityAssignment la in ci)
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using 'value' as the source list for both foreach statements. value apparently contains LiabilityCheckpointInstance objects, so it fails when you try to use it as if it contained LiabilityAssignment  objects.

Did you means to sa: foreach (LiabilityAssignment la in ci.)?